# Dynamically create new sets of DataTable grouped by column and function calls

Tags: c#, dynamic, datatable

I have a DataTable that looks like this:

`| ItemName |ItemValue
     A       3,1
     B       2,2
     C       1,5
     A       2,0
     B       1,4
     A       2,7
     C       1,3
     C       2,1
     B       1,9`

I already did a sort with this code:

`_inputTable = _inputTable.AsEnumerable()
                          .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("ItemName"))
                          .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(r => r.Field<string>("ItemName")))
                          .CopyToDataTable();`

So in the end it should looks like this:

`| ItemName |ItemValue
     A       3,1
     A       2,0
     A       2,7
     B       2,2
     B       1,4
     B       1,9
     C       1,5
     C       1,3
     C       2,1`

Now i want to create it so that it'll group the sets of unique ItemName and dynamically calls a function with only their setsname.

For example at the end there will be 3 sets of dataTable; set of As, Bs, and Cs and it'll call this function 'runMain' 3 times with parameters: runMain("A"), runMain("B"), and runMain("C")

Could someone help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: Your `GroupBy(...).SelectMany(...)` could just be an `OrderBy`.

Comment: I think you want `OrderBy` in your query not `GroupBy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new object to work with:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

then you can do something like:

```
var datas = _inputTable.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("ItemName"))
        .Select(r => 
            new Data
            {
                Key = r.Key, 
                Values = r.Select(x => x.Field<string>("ItemValue")).ToList()
            });

 foreach (var data in datas)
 {
    SomeMethod(data);    
 }
```

since you want to keep your datatable intact for each letter, you can try this:

```
 var tables = _inputTable
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Select(x => x.Field<string>("ItemName"))
           .Distinct()
           .Select(c => dt.Select("ItemName = '" + c + "'").CopyToDataTable())
           .ToList();
```

Comment: Mmm.. interesting but is there a way to have the internal class have string Key and DataTable table which Data.table is a subset of the whole table but only items with "A"s or Bs /Cs respectively

Comment: For this example it'll work what you are saying but i gave a simple example the one i'm dealing with has a lot of columns not just ItemValue so thats why creating a subset of this table would be better

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you if all you need are the unique names.

```
var distinctNames = _inputTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => r.Field<string>("ItemName"))
    .Distinct();

foreach (var name in distinctNames)
{
    runMain(name );    
}
```

Comment: Great this works but when i runMain i only need the dataTable that contains only "A"s, "B"s or "C"s as respectively not the whole table. 
Obviously the following code doesn't work but how could you fix it so it only takes the subset of the whole table with "A"s 

`DataTable inputTable = _inputTable.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(r => r.Field<string>("ItemName"))
                .Where(dt => dt.Equals(name));`

Comment: @civic.sir if you need that data that goes with the names then I suggest you go with Jonesy's answer.